# Vue.js - data in component instead of a generated modal

Tags: vue.js

I have a list of terms that have a description. I need these description to be displayed right after the term name instead of in a modal.

this is the vue component:

```
      Vue.component('taxonomy-list', {
          template : ''+
            '<span><template v-for="(room, index) in event.terms[tax]">' +
              '<template v-if="room.url"><a :href="room.url">{{room.name}}</a></template>' +
//HERE
              '<template v-else-if="room.desc"><a href="#" class="wcs-modal-call" v-on:click="openModal( room, options, $event )">{{room.name}}</a></template>' +
//END
              '<template v-else>{{room.name}}</template>' +
              '<template v-if="index !== (event.terms[tax].length - 1)">, </template>' +
            '</template></span>' ,
          props    : [ 'tax', 'options', 'event', ],
          methods  : {
            openModal: function( item, options, $event ){
              this.$emit( 'open-modal', item, options, $event );
            },
          }
        });
```

on the second case on click it generate a modal with the description that i need.

This is the generated modal:

```
Vue.component( 'modal-taxonomy', {
  template: '#wcs_templates_modal--taxonomy',
    props: [ 'data', 'options', 'content', 'classes' ],
    mixins: [wcs_modal_mixins]
});    

<script type="text/x-template" id="wcs_templates_modal--taxonomy">
    <div class="wcs-modal" :class="classes" v-on:click="closeModal">
        <div class="wcs-modal__box">
            <div class="wcs-modal__inner">
                <a href="#" class="wcs-modal__close ti-close" v-on:click="closeModal"></a>
                <div class="wcs-modal__content wcs-modal__content--full">
                    <h2 v-html="data.name"></h2>
                    <div v-html="data.content"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I just need to print the "data.content" right after the name of the {{room.name}}, but i cant manage to do so...

Thanks guys.

EDIT: thats the modalOpen function:

```
openModal: function( data, options ){
        var $self = this;
        this.data = data;
        this.options = options;
        if( ! this.visible ){
            this.visible = true;
        }
        this.loading = true;

        if( typeof data.start !== 'undefined' ){
            if( typeof this.events[data.id] === 'undefined' ){
                this.getClass( data.id );
            } else {
                this.data.content = this.events[data.id].content;
                this.data.image     = this.events[data.id].image;
                this.loading = ! this.loading;
            }
        } else {
            if( typeof this.taxonomies[data.id] === 'undefined' ){
                this.getTaxonomy( data.id );
            } else {
                this.data.content = this.taxonomies[data.id];
                this.loading = ! this.loading;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `template v-for` ... ? is template name of a component?

Comment: @LiranC he is probably using `<template>` as a wrapper: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt

Comment: @yuriy636, exatly. All the stuff seems banal, but i can't get how to print the description outside of the modal. Original code is not mine, so i'm stuck.

Comment: Need to see what happens in the handler of the `open-modal` event.

Comment: @RoyJ, Added the function, tnx

Comment: So isn't it just `room.content`? `room` is passed as `item` which becomes `data` for the modal component?

Comment: that's what I was also thinking, but `room.content` print an empty result(the taxonomy description have text inside) and so does `room.description` For reference, `room.desc` print a **true** (there is content) and `room.slug` return the slug, so its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal component uses `room.content` to display the description, but that property is initialised only if you call `openModel`, see `this.data.content = this.events[data.id].content;` and `this.data.content = this.taxonomies[data.id];`.

IMO you have two options, either duplicate the `openModel` logic into the HTML or create a *computed* property that returns the description (I'd choose the latter).

EDIT

Actually, a method should be better because you extract the description from `room`. You'll need something like:

```
Vue.component('taxonomy-list', {
      template : ''+
        '<span><template v-for="(room, index) in event.terms[tax]">' +
          '<template v-if="room.url"><a :href="room.url">{{room.name}}</a></template>' +
//HERE
          '<template v-else-if="room.desc"><a href="#" class="wcs-modal-call" v-on:click="openModal( room, options, $event )">{{room.name}}</a></template>' +
//END
          '<template v-else>{{room.name}}</template>' +
// DESCRIPTION
          '{{ description(room) }}' +
// END
          '<template v-if="index !== (event.terms[tax].length - 1)">, </template>' +
        '</template></span>' ,
      props    : [ 'tax', 'options', 'event', ],
      methods  : {
        openModal: function( item, options, $event ){
          this.$emit( 'open-modal', item, options, $event );
        },
        description: function( room ) {
           // insert the logic used by openModal to set content here and return that string
           // this.events[data.id].content or this.taxonomies[data.id]
           return 'description...';
        },
      },
   },
});
```

Comment: Good idea @Figus, but i am a total nood in term of Vue, can u give me an example of this _computed property_?

Comment: In this case, a method should be better. I updated my answer.